# Is there a name for this family of integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gamma-function

This one: $\int_{0}^{\bar{x}}e^{-x^{a}}x^{b}(1-x)^{c}dx,a,b,c\ge0$. When $a=1,c=0,\bar{x}=\infty$ it is the gamma function.

Comment: The integral does not even converge for $a>0$.

Comment: no name, no closed form evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Maple evaluates $\int e^{-x^a}x^b\;dx$ in terms of the Whittaker M function, which 
may also be written as ${}_1F_1$ hypergeometrics.
$$
\int \!{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{a}}}{x}^{b}\,{\rm d}x=
\\
{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-{
x}^{a}/2}}}{ \left( b+1 \right)  \left( a+b+1 \right)  \left( 2\,a+b+1
 \right) } \left(  \left(  \left( a+b+1 \right) {x}^{b/2+1/2-3/2\,a}+{
x}^{b/2+1/2-a/2}a \right) a{{\rm M}_{-{\frac {a-b-1}{2a}},\,{
\frac {2\,a+b+1}{2a}}}\left({x}^{a}\right)}+{x}^{b/2+1/2-3/2\,a}{
{\rm M}_{{\frac {a+b+1}{2a}},\,{\frac {2\,a+b+1}{2a}}}\left({x
}^{a}\right)} \left( a+b+1 \right) ^{2} \right) }
$$